# Turn JSON response into News feed

Tags: html, css, json, web

I am stuck on translating information into a more client-friendly interface. Below is the JSON response I have received from my script. However, I would like to turn this into a standard news feed you would see on a website. What is the best way to go about this?

I am looking to have the image displayed next to the headline, summary, and URL link.

```js
[
  {
    "datetime": 1545215400000,
    "headline": "Voice Search Technology Creates A New Paradigm For Marketers",
    "source": "Benzinga",
    "url": "https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/news/article/8348646549980454",
    "summary": "<p>Voice search is likely to grow by leap and bounds, with technological advancements leading to better adoption and fueling the growth cycle, according to Lindsay Boyajian, <a href=\"http://loupventures.com/how-the-future-of-voice-search-affects-marketers-today/\">a guest contributor at Loup Ventu...",
    "related": "AAPL,AMZN,GOOG,GOOGL,MSFT",
    "image": "https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/news/image/7594023985414148",
    "lang": "en",
    "hasPaywall": true
  }
]
```

Below is my js to initiate the pull.

```
    function news() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var newsfeed = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      document.getElementById("news").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/spy/news/last/1?token=pk_6925213461cb489b8c04a632e18c25dd", false);
  xhttp.send();
};
```

I use this in my HTML to display the raw JSON before manipulation into what I want.

```
<div id=news class="text-white-50">
      <script>
        document.onreadystatechange = function() {
           if (document.readyState === 'complete')
           {
              news();
           }
         };
       </script>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you post some of the code you have tried? Also if you are getting the json response from your script, you can use js to append the data to your html

Comment: Updated in edit - displayed in Codepen: https://codepen.io/ethor11/pen/LYpGLEM

Comment: You parsed the responseText as a variable name newsfeed. So instead of using `this.responseText`, use `newsfeed[0]["headline"]` where setting the innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

i think you make some html

```html
sudo codes...
<div>
<p id="foo1"></p>
<p id="foo2"></p>
<img id="fooImg"></img>
</div>
```

when you got response json setup in html

```js
sudo codes...
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var newsfeed = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    document.getElementById("news").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    document.getElementById("foo1").innerHTML = newsfeed.foo;
    document.getElementById("foo2").innerHTML = newsfeed.bar;
    document.getElementById("fooImg").src = newsfeed.someImgSrc;
}
```